# How to add event Key_Down to dotnetbar ribbon comboxbox?

Tags: c#, combobox

I use dotnetbar to design UI.

```
private DevComponents.DotNetBar.ComboBoxItem AddressTextBox;
```

but it dont have event Key_Down
I use

```
ComboBox address = (ComboBox)AddressTextBox.ContainerControl;
            address.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(address_KeyDown);
```

But It has error `Unable to cast object of type 'DevComponents.DotNetBar.RibbonBar' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'.`

Any idea?

Comment: You can't cast something to a `ComboBox` if it isn't a `ComboBox` control.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `AddressTextBox.ContainerControl` does not hold an object of the **type** `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`